# Implementation details of implicit arguments

Tags: implementation, implicit-argument

How do the implicit arguments work in proof assistants such as Agda or Coq? Specifically, how are the blanks filled in? What kind of resolution algorithm is used?

Are there any papers written about implicit arguments?

Comment: Take a look at Ulf Norell's thesis "Towards a practical programming
language based on dependent type
theory" and https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/elaboration-zoo

Comment: Two other papers of interest: "Higher-Order Dynamic Pattern Unification for Dependent Types and Records" and "A tutorial implementation of dynamic pattern unification". Ulf Norell's thesis discusses the insertion of meta variables, which can then be solved via unification.

Comment: @AlberttenNapel The tutorial is way too hard. Are these the only sources to dynamic pattern unification?

Comment: The implementation from github.com/AndrasKovacs/elaboration-zoo is the simplest one I know.

Comment: @AlberttenNapel I found this through citations, and it seems conceptually simplest of them all. https://lopezjuan.com/en/event/2020/licentiate/

Comment: Thanks, haven't seen that one yet. Though if you are implementing then the algorithm from elaboration-zoo is still much simpler (but less powerful).

Comment: @AlberttenNapel Here's another one. "Eliminating the problems of hidden-lambda insertion" http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/MScThesisJohanssonLloyd.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is any detailed paper description of this for Coq, however there is one for [Matita](http://www.cs.unibo.it/%7Easperti/PAPERS/lmcs_types_2010.pdf) which as far as I know is quite close to how Coq does things.

Unification is taken as a black box there, if you want to open that box, the best I know of in the Coq ecosystem is [UniCoq](https://github.com/unicoq/unicoq) and [its accompanying paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01671925). Again, it is not what actually happens in the internals of Coq, but it should be close enough to satisfy some curiosity.